# Centering certain sentences within a paragraph

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'd like to center (also left-align and right-align) a piece of sentence **within** one paragraph, which can be easily done in Word by `[newline] + [center this line] + [newline]`. In LaTeX, however, the `centering` command affects the whole paragraph, and to affect only groups, it requires a `\par` at the start and the end of that group. Meanwhile, the `center` environment adds additional vertical space. I know there's a `centerline` command that fits my need, but it seems there isn't any counterparts in terms of "left-align" or "right-align". Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
I want to center\\
"This piece of text"\\
within this paragraph.

I don't want to break the
{\par\centering paragraph like\par}
this.

How to achieve the effect\\
\centerline{without \texttt{centerline}}\\
or \begin{center}
the \texttt{center} environment?
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you adds some background information about the intended use cases of such an alignment?

Answer (score 3):

## New answer

As pointed out by [@campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570666/centering-certain-sentences-within-a-paragraph/570674?noredirect=1#comment1438144_570674) you don't have to define your own counterparts, as they are actually already contained in LaTeX and called `\leftline` and `\rightline`. So you can use

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\hsize=5cm % just so that line breaks are a bit earlier
This is some longish text that is long and needs me to centre some
material\\
\centerline{here is center}
Also I'd like to display some stuff to the left\\
\leftline{here is left}
and to put something on the right\\
\rightline{here is right.}
\end{document}
```

---

## Old answer

Kept for posterity.

You can get the counterparts for left- and right-alignment by defining them. The following should do. Note that only contents not wider than a single line work as intended, inside of `\@@line` no automatic linebreaking will occur.

In case you're wondering `\hss` is a glue that **h**orizontally **s**tretches or **s**hrinks just as necessary for the specified space being filled (`\@@line` is a single `\hbox` which should be as wide as the current `\hsize`, so the width of the text).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\leftalignline[1]{\@@line{#1\hss}}
\newcommand\rightalignline[1]{\@@line{\hss#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hsize=5cm % just so that line breaks are a bit earlier
This is some longish text that is long and needs me to centre some
material\\
\centerline{here is center}
Also I'd like to display some stuff to the left\\
\leftalignline{here is left}
and to put something on the right\\
\rightalignline{here is right.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Uhm, your `\leftalignline` and `\rightalignline` already exist in the LaTeX kernel with (almost) precisely those definitions. They are called `\leftline` and `\rightline`.

Comment: @campa oh, I didn't know these... Thank you!

Comment: I think they are not really documented LaTeX macros. They belong to the bunch of plain TeX macros which have been more or less silently inherited.

Comment: @campa well, the same is true for `\centerline`, afaik, but I just didn't know that `\leftline` and `\rightline` did make it into LaTeX as well.

Comment: That's why I said "silently" `:-)`